# Ajax Request with CORS not going through

Tags: ajax, cors

I'm trying to make a cross domain request. I am aware of CORS and want to test the call from for example w3schools as a domain.

I'm using Jersey for the REST API and an Apache server , and did the following :

```
    ResponseBuilder rb = Response.status(status).entity(mapper.writeValueAsBytes(data)).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    **EDITED **
    rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, OPTIONS");
    rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","*");



   return rb.build
```

When i view my response headers from just calling my API from the browser I see

Access-Control-Allow-Headers:* 
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, OPTIONS 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* 
Cache-Control:private 
Content-Length:2523 
Content-Type:application/json 
Date:Wed, 17 Apr 2013 20:16:20 GMT 
 
Expires:Wed, 31 Dec 1969 16:00:00 PST 
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1

but when I want to really test it using a different domain ie in W3 schools, I have the following -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
</script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){

   $.ajax({
        url: "url", // this is a real URL replaced with just url
        type: 'GET',

        success: function(content) { console.log("ok"); },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {   
            console.log("error");
        },
        complete: function() { console.log("complete"); }
     });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP GET request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
```

I always get a XMLHttpRequest cannot load :url:. Origin http://www.w3schools.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

My Request headers  are

Accept: */* 
Origin:http://www.w3schools.com 
Referer:http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit_view.asp?x=0.8691769954748452 
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31

I tried testing the above in jsfiddle as well, but got the same error .

Note :  My URL is still just on my localhost, is it possible that that is the issue?

What am I missing?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928266/cross-domain-rest-jersey-web-services-with-cors

Comment: Can you share the request headers as well? My guess is you will need an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header, or you will need to handle OPTIONS requests. Also note that your response header says `Allow-Control-Allow-Methods`, and it should be `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`

Comment: @anazimok : By going to that URL I was able to navigate to http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html , where it tells me to apply the headers I seem to have applied? Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: @monsur : I have updated my question with the request headers. I shall try your suggestions right now and let you know

Comment: @Rahul: Are you sure w3schools.com supports CORS? I have tried hitting site i know does support cors from jquery and it works just fine, while w3schools.com does not. See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/anazimok/3J2F6/

Comment: @anazimok : So I tried applying my code from jsfiddle instead. I get the same issue . I changed my headers to just accept all. ie I did  rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*"); , but still get the same error. Any other possibilities?

Comment: @monsur : I applied rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","*"); and changed Allow-Control-Allow-Methods to Access-Control-Allow-Methods by editing to rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET"); , but get the same issue.

Comment: @Rahul: Have you tried hitting the url I put in jsfiddle? I don't believe that w3schools supports CORS.

Comment: @anazimok : Yes, I went to the URL, your URL works good (as I can see the ok in the console), but when I plug my REST api in there, it gives the same error but with jsfiddle as origin i.e XMLHttpRequest cannot load "URL". Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.  Note I have replaced my API url with just "URL"

Comment: Just adding another note, my URL is still just a localhost API, is it possible that that is the issue?

Comment: @Rahul: try adding "OPTIONS" to "Access-Control-Allow-Methods". e.g. .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, OPTIONS")

Comment: @anazimok : I added options, so now my Response headers returns Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, OPTIONS . I still get the same error :/ Does the fact that my REST API is still on a local deploy do anything?

Comment: @Rahul: Monitor your request on the client side. Use firebug or deve tools see if request sends the CORS headers. If it doesn't then it is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed my problem.

I had to do this

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url: 'url',
   xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   },
   success : function(data) {alert(data); }
});
```

Since my REST service was one that needed authentication, I guess it needed authentication before anything at all happened, so once I did that and specified my origin in my response, I was able to get it to work.